# Kernel Error in R Notebook using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to use R within the jupyter notebook.

I went to my R shell and ran

```
install.packages(c('rzmq','repr','IRkernel','IRdisplay'),
             repos = c('http://irkernel.github.io/', getOption('repos')))
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Then I loaded up my ipython notebook and created a new notebook using the now available R extension. How ever when I access the notebook I run into this kernal error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\base\handlers.py", line 394, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 53, in     post
    model = sm.create_session(path=path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 66, in create_session
    kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 84, in start_kernel
    kernel_name=kernel_name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\multikernelmanager.py", line 112, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
**kw)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\launcher.py", line 202, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Nina Kate\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: If you go to a command prompt and run `R`, does it start R? If not, you'll need to add the directory containing `R.exe` to your system path. See here for instructions on changing that: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I have the same issue here. Mac OS, I am able to start r from the terminal.

Comment: Same here in Windows 7. Can start R in shell but get kernel error in jupyter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having exactly the same error in Windows 7.
I added R to PATH environment variables and I was able to run it on shell but I was still having the kernel error in Jupyter.

The Kernel started working [when installed system wide](http://irkernel.github.io/installation/) using:

```
IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)
```

instead of the first installation option:

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Note that it is necessary to set both parameters, the PATH variable and the R system wide install.

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed the warning up top about a missing index in the irkernel repo:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://irkernel.github.io/src/contrib:
   cannot download all files
```

The [new installation](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel#installation) steps worked for me (in R 3.3 console):

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel') # IRkernel-master.tar.gz
IRkernel::installspec()  # register kernel in the current R install
IRkernel::installspec(name = 'ir33', displayname = 'R 3.3')  # ir32, R 3.2
```

When you restart `jupyter notebook`, an "R 3.3" entry should appear in the list of kernels.

Comment: I am actually quite shocked that this worked!! I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple of hours. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows 10 and not using Anaconda, then try this;

Review your existing kernel file with Notepad.  File is located:

~ AppData\Roaming\Jupyter\kernels

This file will show the version of R that was used when Jupyter was installed.  If you changed or upgraded the version of R currently being used, then R Kernel will not work in Jupyter.

R Studio -> Tools -> Global Options -> Change , to review versions of R installed on PC.  If the current version of R is different than the version in the kernel file, select that other version of R.  Close R Studio and reopen to verify version being used.  Close R Studio and open Jupyter Notebook and select the R kernel.  R kernel should now work.