# R kernel for jupyter notebook dead upon installation

Tags: python, r, ipython, jupyter

I've just installed the R kernel for jupyter notebook on windows 10 and am getting the same error as OP in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816856/kernel-error-in-r-notebook-using-jupyter-notebook). Pasted below is the error shown when I click on the "Kernel error" button.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 436, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 56, in post
    model = sm.create_session(path=path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 66, in create_session
    kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 84, in start_kernel
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 109, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 239, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 186, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 108, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried a lot of things and I'm not sure if I'm making it worse.

-I've added `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin` to my system path so R could be run on the command line. I've also tried all the combinations of adding `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin` and `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64` to my system path as well as user path. In my notebook UI under the drop down menu for new notebooks I actually now see two R options, and I can't seem to get rid of it.

-I've tried running both `> IRkernel::installspec()` and `> IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)` in RStudio. I've since then deleted the .json kernel file in `%APPDATA%\jupyter\kernels` because I was trying to remove the R duplication I'm seeing in the notebook.

-I've tried adding a `kernel.json` file in `C:\Users\[username]\.ipython\kernels\R_kernel` with the content

```
{"argv": ["C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.0/bin/R.exe","-e","IRkernel::main()",
"--args","{connection_file}"],
"display_name":"R"
}
```

And none of these have worked. Any help is appreciated. Python 2 runs fine with my notebook.

Comment: Have you tried to just use the Continuum Analytics install? It requires significantly less care & feeding.

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I'm worried about it creating even more conflicts. I couldn't find any clear instruction on how to uninstall this kernel. I've deleted some .json files like I mentioned but the duplicate R option hasn't even gone away yet.

Comment: please see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816856/kernel-error-in-r-notebook-using-jupyter-notebook/32910297#32910297)

Comment: @joaquin, I have actually already tried what you suggested in my beginning post.

Comment: @Remy Maybe you changed too much things. that's common when fiddling around with something that doesn't work. Maybe you should clean everything and restart again. I did not used RStudio. Just jupyter and the R default gui. Win7 64bits and last versions of jupyter and R.